# Sorting multidimensional array for scores using temporary variables

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, sorting, multidimensional-array

Hi guys having some trouble sorting a multidimensional array containing the scores for different users in the leaderboard form of a game I am making. I have tried to sort the scores for each user in descending order using temporary variables and then output this with no success. Any help would be much appreciated thanks. I should add that I have only recently started coding and have to do this project as part of my work for school so I am aware that it may not be very efficient and seem very novice.

Here is my method for sorting
( [i, 2] is the score value stored as a string )

```
private void sortScore(string[,] sort)
{
    bool didSwap;
    do
    {
        didSwap = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < userNumber; i++)
        {
            if (i < (userNumber-1))
            {
                if (Convert.ToInt32(sort[i, 2]) > Convert.ToInt32(sort[i + 1, 2]))
                {
                    string temp = sort[i + 1, 2];
                    sort[i + 1, 2] = sort[i, 2];
                    sort[i, 2] = temp;
                }
            }            
        }
    } while (didSwap);
    for (int j = 0; j < userNumber; j++)
    {
        rtbScoreboard.AppendText("Name: " + sort[j, 0] + "\t" + "Score: " + sort[j, 2] + Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain your input and expected output with an example?

Comment: You are sorting in increasing order : Convert.ToInt32(sort[i, 2]) > Convert.ToInt32(sort[i + 1, 2]

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ!

```
var sortedScores = Enumerable.Range(0, sort.GetLength(0)) //number of items
.Select(x => new
{
    Name = sort[x, 0],
    Score = Convert.ToInt32(sort[x, 2])
}) //converting to a meaningful structure
.OrderByDescending(x => x.Score) //sort in descending order by score
.ToList();

//building output, I don't know what is userNumber, It is a global variable 
// that might store number of players to show in score board.
for (int j = 0; j < userNumber; j++)
{
    rtbScoreboard.AppendText("Name: " + sortedScores[j].Name + "\t" + "Score: " + sortedScores[j].Score + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

You should not store data like that. Using a multidimensional array to store names and score is not a good idea. Try defining a class like `Player` which has Properties for storing data like `Name` and `Score`. Then store instances of `Player`s in a list.

Comment: I know that this is not the best way to store the user details but unfortunately as part of the project we were told to do so using a binary file. Thanks for the reply

Comment: Just tried your method and works perfectly thanks I need to finish this project this weekend so thanks very much for helping me out. As I said I'm just starting out in coding so still learning so sometimes I'm not sure how to best tackle different problems

Answer (score 0):

You fail to set didSwap to true

```
bool didSwap;
do
{
    didSwap = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < userNumber-1; i++)
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(sort[i, 2]) > Convert.ToInt32(sort[i + 1, 2]))
        {
            string temp = sort[i + 1, 2];
            sort[i + 1, 2] = sort[i, 2];
            sort[i, 2] = temp;
            didSwap = true;
        }           
    }
}   while (didSwap);
```